# Facebook API: can't delete event post, returns: (#100) Invalid post id

Tags: php, facebook, api, events

I post something on my event's wall on behalf of my user:

```
$event_id = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

$message = array(
  'access_token' => $token,
  'message' => 'This is just a test...',
  'name' => 'Title',
  'caption' => "Caption goes here"
);

$result = $facebook->api($event_id."/feed", "POST", $message);
```

Then I read out the post ID like this:

```
$post_id = $result["id"];

// for example: 387914681250830_387939784581653
// where the format is EVENTID_POSTID
```

...and I try to delete the same post:

```
try {
  $facebook->api($post_id, "DELETE");
}
catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
  $error = $e->getMessage();
  print $error;
}
```

and the result is this:

```
(#100) Invalid post id
```

I even tried these versions (assuming that post ID is 387914681250830_387939784581653):

```
$facebook->api("/387914681250830_387939784581653/", "DELETE"); // (#100) invalid post_id

$facebook->api("/387939784581653", "DELETE"); // Unsupported delete request.

$facebook->api("/387914681250830/feed/387939784581653", "DELETE"); // Unknown path components: /387939784581653
```

So now I'm stucked.
It's funny that the API returns a POST_ID which turns out to be INVALID. :-((

Any ideas how can I delete a post (created by my app) on an event wall (owned by me)?

Comment: The /387914681250830_387939784581653 is the correct end-point, just made a test with the Graph API Explorer. Locate the post using [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) and try to delete it. If it still returns invalid post id, fire bug report to Facebook.

Comment: Thanks! I've tested it using the Graph API Explorer. Selected my app from the dropdown list, then pasted the post ID, selected DELETE, and submitted... Same error: (#100) invalid post_id

Comment: And when you select GET do you get the post data? Maybe it's already deleted. If you get the post data, but can't delete it, and if the post is yours / you are administrator of the page/event?

Comment: I can't even locate the post in the Graph API Explorer... It returns "false". :-( Yes, I'm the owner of the post and also the event. The post is not deleted... I can view it like this: www.facebook.com/203400569781524

Comment: Does the post exists in Facebook? Can you provide a link?

Comment: Now I created a public event and posted something, so You can test it:
Message ID: 466012806759245_466013480092511
You can view it here: http://www.facebook.com/466013480092511

By the way, the result of the posting command was this:
array(1) { ["id"]=> string(31) "466012806759245_466013480092511" }

Comment: But the ID of the post is 466012806759245_466014720092387 ?!

Comment: That's another post. The first post (with an image, title etc.) is 466012806759245_466013480092511, the second post has only text, that's 466012806759245_466014720092387. In the Graph API Explorer I can't GET neither of them... But I can view them like this: http://www.facebook.com/466013480092511 and http://www.facebook.com/466014720092387